# We are 3 hours away from New York

Tags: word-usage

A man is driving to New York with his son. His son says:

Dad, where are we?

The man says:

***We are three hours away from New York.***

(I mean they will arrive in New York in 3 hours)

Is this phrase ***3 hours away from New York*** is correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct and common.

Comment: Yep, perfectly fine.  Though note that similar wording might be used to refer to distance by air:  "But Mom, we'll only be living three hours away" might mean that there are reasonably frequent airline flights between the two locations, and the typical flight time is three hours.

Comment: Yes it is certainly idiomatic, though apparently illogical.

Comment: What do you mean by saying  apparently illogical?

Comment: ... The prototypical sense of '... away from' is a distance not a measure of journey-time. (I replied for WS2 as I'm in a _prototypical_-using mood.)

Comment: What do you say when you want to indicate the measure of journey-time?

Comment: @WS2 - In pre-motorized times distances were often expressed as "a two-hour walk" of "an hour's ride".  Nothing illogical about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly correct; not to mention, fairly common.